# Can a swashbuckler parry creatures he cannot see if he has blindfight and combat reflexes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

Can a [swashbuckler](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/) parry an attack from an invisible creature or creature they cannot see if they can make AOOs while flatfooted via [combat reflexes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-reflexes-combat/) and have [blindfight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/blind-fight-combat/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

**Can a swashbuckler parry an attack from an invisible creature, or creature they cannot see?**

Breaking it down/apart (at the request of Erudaki).

**Precondition:** Swashbuckler class is specifically mentioned to limit the scope of "parry" to the use of the class Deed "Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex)" (OPaR). Other forms of parry are not considered for this answer.

**Precondition:** swashbuckler has an AoO available (i.e. has not used all AoO they are entitled to).

**Precondition:** swashbuckler has a panache point to spend to use the OPaR Deed.

**Precondition:** invisible creature is in melee with swashbuckler as OPaR only applies to melee attacks against the swashbuckler as explicitly stated in the OPaR description.

**Possible assistance:** Combat Reflexes allow AoO while flat-footed. (Turns out this doesn't come into play in this specific situation.)

**Possible assistance:** Blind-Fight allows rerolls on misses against concealed opponents and prevents the loss of Dexterity bonus to AC against invisible opponents and prevents the +2 bonus to hit given to an invisible creature attacking you in melee. (Turns out this doesn't come into play in this specific situation.)

Looking at the Deed: "[Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/)" (OPaR)

1. Requirement: 1st Level swashbuckler = granted,
2. Requirement: 1 panache point to spend = granted,
3. Requirement: AoO available to spend = granted, all PCs have at least one per round.
4. Action: Make an attack roll AS IF IT WERE AN AoO* = granted,

(* I think this wording is used so that the AoO expended by OPaR cannot qualify for other adjustments AoOs might get from other abilities or feats the PC may possess. It does everything a normal AoO does but doesn't qualify as a prerequisite for anything.)

5. The invisible creature is in melee with swashbuckler therefore is in a threatened square.
   (I cannot find any text in invisibility references to say the square isn't threatened, only that the swashbuckler wouldn't know which square the invisible attacker is in, or if it were in one at all... unless they pass a DC40 Perception check to pinpoint the square containing the invisible creature.)

It turns out it is irrelevant to the result whether the Perception check is passed or not, as the attacker remains invisible. If the Perception check is passed then the 5' square is know, but according to invisibility

> *"If a character tries to attack an invisible creature whose location he has pinpointed, he attacks normally, but the invisible creature
> still benefits from full concealment (and thus a 50% miss chance)."*

Full Concealment = Total Concealment (Sloppy English equivalency notwithstanding)

Under Concealment, subtopic Total Concealment, last sentence

> *"You can’t execute an attack of opportunity against an opponent with total concealment, even if you know what square or squares the
> opponent occupies."*

Therefore you cannot use an AoO against an invisible creature even if it is pinpointed.
OPaR states:

> *"The swashbuckler makes an attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity;"*

These two rules clearly answer this question with a resounding NO.

Even if that didn't end the question...

6. Invisible creature attacks swashbuckler

-- Here is where English language causes issues between description and rules --

OPaR says

> *"The swashbuckler must declare the use of this ability after the
> creature’s attack is announced, but before its attack roll is made."*

-- I contest that "announced" does not mean the invisible creature says "I stab at thee!". An invisible attack is NOT "announced" in any way other than for rules purposes, it is at best a meta-announcement. The swashbuckler has no inkling IF an attack is coming, let alone WHEN. It makes no logical sense to be able to block something you cannot see... unless you know... magic. However OPaR is (Ex) not (Sp) not even (Su) so it is NOT magic.

> *"Extraordinary abilities are non-magical. They are, however, not
> something that just anyone can do or even learn to do without
> extensive training. Effects or areas that suppress or negate magic
> have no effect on extraordinary abilities."*

If the swashbuckler cannot know when an attack is coming before it hits them, and potentially never knows if an attack misses them, then they have no cue to declare anything. OPaR cannot even be triggered in this situation!

Comment: Was just coming back to this question because I remembered that line in Total Concealment

Comment: @niekell The problem still remain: Are you making an AoO when using OPaR?
Because the total concealment make you immune to AoO not other things and since OPaR is not an AoO but just let you spend one AoO to do something else is really debatable that you are immune to OPaR. The part of the attack declaration is totally opinion based since there is no written rule on what is an attack declaration (ie: the GM tells you are under attack and then roll the dice so is too much variable from table to table)

Comment: @Mouza if you want to argue that, your gunna have to find rules that support it. "As if it were an attack of opportunity" seems to lean more towards what Niekell is saying. Can you find any examples of texts or rules that say "as if it were XYZ" and do not use the rules for XYZ?

Comment: @Erudaki I don't think this kind of debate can bring to an answer about an ambiguous rule like this because I can simply answer to you that nowhere, literally nowhere, there is written that an opportune parry is an attack of opportunity. For what we know, rule as written, is not even an attack since an attack by the general rule is "An attack roll represents your attempt to strike your opponent on your turn in a round. When you make an attack roll, you roll a d20 and add your attack bonus. If your result equals or beats the target’s Armor Class, you hit and deal damage." (part 1).

Comment: @Erudaki and to me just this example is not using the rule for attacking. You are not attacking and an attack of opportunity is an attack. You are using something that use the same bonus (attack roll) to do something different. I'm not english native language so I'm the first to say that I'm not sure about it...but in my language there is a lot of difference between "roll a check as if it were an attack of opportunity" and "roll an attack opportunity".

Comment: I am specifically aiming to avoid speculation, which is why I asked the question on this website. This answer backs up what it claims with examples and information from rules. OPaR states its an attack roll like an AOO, and both of those rules are pointed out in this answer and support its claim. There are plenty of examples in the rules where "Like XYZ" means it follows the rules for XYZ.

Comment: @Erudaki It's hard to avoid speculation when a rule is ambiguous.The accepted answer, for example, is pure speculation since there is not written that you can not parry an enemy that doesn't take AoO. The only limitation on parry is that you must threat the enemy, the enemy must attack you with a melee attack, you can spend (not use) an AoO and spend a panache point. There are no other limitation. With this interpretation you are giving a lot of malus on this ability because it stops working on enemy with total concealment, cover and so on. It is really a huge nerf. Anyway your table your rule

Comment: @Erudaki Anyway since this is becoming a debate and even if really interesting I don't think it is allowed by the stack rules. Good game and have fun ;)

Comment: @Mouza I agree the rules could be a lot clearer. If you envision logically how the Deed works, it is nonsense to be able to parry an attack from an invisible creature. It just cannot be seen coming. At best you might get in a lucky parry which just randomly happens to block one attack of many. If it takes a DC40 Perception to tell which square an invisible attacker is in, it would take a Perception of what? 60? 80? to tell their invisible weapon is coming for you. I want to say it is inconceivable but it is more likely just insanely, highly, improbable.

Comment: @niekell Actually when in combat the DC to spot the square where an invisible enemy stands is 0 (DC 20 - 20 because in combat) and in reality if an invisible enemy attacks a target, that target knows automatically the square where the invisible enemy is. The problematic point in my opinion is that with this answer you are imposing a great number of limitations to this class feature and in the rule there are not such limitations like for example the impossibility to parry attacks done by enemies with cover. You just need to drink a potion of distortion to become immune to parry.

Comment: @Mouza surely it is DC20 for pinpointing the square "in combat". DC0 to know they're within 30 ft. If they just took a swing/shot to be "in combat", it seems obvious they're within 30 ft. so DC0* (*adjusted for range) seems totally warranted. Not all abilities work all the time, why should OPaR be one that does? (Rhetorical, it shouldn't be.)
The situation renders it ineffective, many other situations render other abilities ineffective, it is actually a very common occurrence. A Deed you can get at 1st level being ineffective against a spell gained at 3rd (Wiz) seems fine to me.

Comment: @niekell Well there is a difference between an ability that doesn't work because it is written that doesn't work in particular situations (like sneak attack) and an ability that doesn't work because we think it or "it makes sense". To me that OPaR doesn't work against enemies that are not taking AoO is a huge limitations (a simple cover gain you immunity vs OPaR) to an already limited class but the rule is ambiguous so i totally agree with you that CAN work as you say.

Comment: That is also false Mouza. You need total cover to be immune to AOO. Or need to be stealthed and unseen. Cover just grants +4 AC.

Answer (score -3):

**Yes, he can...**

First of all the invisible condition is an effect that you GAIN not a malus that you APPLY to someone else:

> Invisible: Invisible creatures are visually undetectable. An invisible creature gains a +2 bonus on attack rolls against a sighted opponent, and ignores its opponent’s Dexterity bonus to AC (if any). See the invisibility special ability.

As we can see the condition itself does two things: 1) you gain an attack bonus and 2) your target has no dex bonus to AC... the target **is not** flat-footed. Flat-footed is another condition.

Other than this the invisibility special ability says:

- While they can’t be seen, invisible creatures can be heard, smelled, or felt
- Invisibility makes a creature undetectable by vision, including darkvision
- Not immune to critical hits **but** immune to extra damage (ranger favored enemy, sneak attack...swashbuckler precision damage too i think)
- If the invisible creature is adjacent to the attacked creature it gains total concealment otherwise the attacked creature need to find a way to pinpoint the invisible creature
- Many other things... (like invisible creature leaves tracks, displace liquids and so on)

Now, going to the swashbuckler parry/reposte:

> Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex): At 1st level, when an opponent makes a melee attack against the swashbuckler, she can spend 1 panache point and expend a use of an attack of opportunity to attempt to parry that attack. The swashbuckler makes an attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity. [...]

Now we can see different things:

- Opportune Parry and Riposte **is not** an attack of opportunity. It costs a use of an attack of opportunity and you attack *as if* it is an attack of opportunity..because it isn't.(i hope this part is clear enough).
- Nothing specifies conditions about the state of the attacker. This means that we don't know if it's required to see the attacker or to hear the attacker and so on.

And that's it.

Nothing prevents actually to use opportune parry and riposte versus an invisible attacker...and you do not need those two feats at all.
You do not need feats at all since when you are fighting an invisible enemy you **are not** flat footed (so combat reflexes isn't needed) and blind fight gives you more AC (since you retain DEX to armor) but that's it.

...**but**...

What happens if your GM treat opportune parry and riposte **as a real attack of opportunity**?
Well...in this case **you can not** make opportune parry and riposte since you can not make attack of opportunity to an opponent with total concealment :

> [...] You can’t execute an attack of opportunity against an opponent with total concealment, even if you know what square or squares the opponent occupies.

So your only chances in this case are:

- see invisibility (in some way)
- remove your dependency from eyesight (like echolocation for example)
- [Greater Blind-Fight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-blind-fight-combat) (or similar effect that decreases or removes the total concealment from your opponent)

I hope it's enough, good game!

Marco.

Comment: I don't understand how you disassociate the parry being an "attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity" from the requirements of making an attack of opportunity

Comment: You still need Greater Blind-Fight in order to parry, unless you just parry into the open space (and suffer the subsequent chance of failure).

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question. If you ignore the line that says its like an attack of opportunity you can, but if you consider it like an attack of opportunity you cant? Which is it actually considered tho?

Total concealment vs is parry only able to be used when AOOs can be used is the core of the question.

Comment: @Erudaki Rule as written parry and riposte is not an attack of opportunity. It costs an use of attack of opportunity and the attack roll is the same as the attack of opportunity and for this reason I can imagine that to some people it can be a situation with a lot of discussion and assumptions and for this reason I've added what you can do if you treat as an attack of opportunity or not.

Comment: @Ifusaso To me there is difference between " the creature does not provoke AoO" (in case of invisible creature) and "when you are attacked you can spend an AoO to make an attack roll and try to parry the attack". A lot of difference to be honest but I'm the first to say that the rule about this is really vague.

Comment: In other sections of the rules, there are cases where "like a(n) XYZ" means it follows the same rules as XYZ. It is fairly interpretable that by RAW it means either. If you can find or provide clarification one way or the other that would be preferable, because right now your answer is playing both sides so to speak.

Comment: "You can’t attack an opponent that has total concealment," Since you make an attack roll as part of parry and riposte, does this mean you cannot use it? This is really the crux of what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex) says "The swashbuckler makes an attack roll as if she were making an attack of opportunity" so all AoO conditions apply. Since Total Concealment disallows attacks of opportunity against the concealed creature, this means Opportune Parry and Riposte (Ex) will not work against an invisible creature (even if you know which square they are in). Nor should it really, for how do you pre-declare your Deed when you can't see the attack coming?!

Comment: @Erudaki There is not written the sentence "like an XXX". There is written "you spends one AoO to make an attack roll as if you were making one"...but you are not making an AoO. Sincerely if I read the rule and definition of AoO I don't find connection with a parry. A parry doesn't do damage, doesn't target AC...but anyway in my answer I clearly state that if you treat parry as AoO you can't parry it since there is total concealment. You think I need to be more clear about the GM decisions on it?

Comment: @niekell I don't see your point. Actually even if the enemy is invisible, or behind cover, or stealthed the attack declaration has to be done since he want to make an attack roll. Since there is an attack declaration there is nothing in the rules to prevent the opportune parry and riposte since the only limitation for a swashbuckler is this:  "The swashbuckler must declare the use of this ability after the creature’s attack is announced, but before its attack roll is made."

Comment: I moreso would like the answer to take a side. It feels like it is riding the middle ground with its language saying it can be both. It is too hard to tell which way is how the rules should function rather than just interpretation.

Comment: @niekell could you make your comment into an answer? I think it would be good to have that as an answer along side Mouza's for anyone who finds this question in the future

Comment: @Erudaki Every rule is interpreted. Even the Law is subject to interpretetation by the judges. I understand what are you saying and I apologize if you find my answer problematic but in this case there is ambiguity in the rule itself since there is not written that a parry IS an attack of opportunity but it cost one use of AoO to use a parry. So your choice are two: you can treat a parry AS an effective AoO even if is not written that it is an AoO or not...and I've just tried to explain both cases in my answer.

Comment: @Jason_c_o You don't actually care about miss chance via concealment, because whether the result of the attack roll is a hit or miss has no bearing on if the attack is parried, [otherwise 1's and 20's would matter](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/184217).

Comment: "Nothing specifies conditions about the state of the attacker. This means that we don't know if it's required to see the attacker or to hear the attacker and so on." That's the OP's question. I feel like this answer confounds the issue and doesn't actually address it.